# Oracle to_char in query is not working

Tags: oracle

Im trying to run this below query but its seems to be error

For those data types are `varchar`

**Query**

```
select * 
  from RP_REPORT_TEMP 
 where to_char(START_DATE,'FM DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS AM') 
          >= 'May 01 2016 00:00:00' 
   and to_char(END_DATE,'FM DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS PM') 
          <= 'May 31 2016 11:59:00' 
   and lower(rid) like '%a001%' 
 order by CAST(cid as INTEGER) asc
```

**Table**

```
|RID                 |START_DATE                 |END_DATE                     |
|--------------------|-------------------------- |-----------------------------|
|A001                |May  1 2016 12:00:00:000AM |May  31 2016 12:00:00:000PM  |
|A001                |May  1 2016 12:00:00:000AM |May  31 2016 12:00:00:000PM  |
|A001                |May  1 2016 12:00:00:000AM |May  31 2016 12:00:00:000PM  |
```

While i tried to execute this query. Query return some error. How can i fix this ?

***Error***

```
SQL Error [1722] [42000]: ORA-01722: invalid number
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Comment: No idea why you added tags for MySQL or SQL Server since `TO_CHAR()` does not exist in either DBMS. I've assumed it was an error and removed them. If you're actually looking for a cross-DBMS method to manipulate dates please edit the question.

Comment: What is the datatype of the following columns, please? `START_DATE`, `END_DATE`, `CID`

Comment: `varchar` @Boneist need to chage the datetype ?

Comment: @QuestionUser I knew that was the issue. You performing the wrong operations with the **datatype** you have. Anyways try and remove meridiam indicators since you are using `HH24` in your OP and use proper spacing with meridiams indicators

Comment: There are a number of things wrong with your comparisons - the format of the start/end columns doesn't match the format of the strings you're comparing them to, so you'd likely get no rows returned anyway. Also, a string of `May 12 2017 20:01:03` is between `01 2016 00:00:00` and `31 2016 11:59:00`, so your comparison logic is off too. If you're comparing dates, you should keep the datatype as `DATE` (ie. convert strings into dates using to_date()); it makes things much easier - you've got all that inbuilt date validation built in, for starters!

Comment: **Never**, ever store dates or timestamps in `varchar` columns. Just don't.

Comment: can you give me the example @KurtMiller ?

Comment: @QuestionUser For instance t:  `TO_DATE(
    'January 15, 1989, 11:00 A.M.',
    'Month dd, YYYY, HH:MI A.M.',
     'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')` That one is not using `HH24` plus is specifying the date language (hopefully your defaullt date language is American). Check this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm . Anyways since you table fields are varchar, I recommand they be stored in proper date format (though varchar) then do a to_date to_date comparison (see Avi answer below if you want to use HH24 or Alvaro ansswer if not using HH24 )

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `TO_DATE()` on the date instead?

```
select * from RP_REPORT_TEMP 
where START_DATE >= to_date('May 01 2016 12:00:00 AM','MON DD YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
  and END_DATE <= to_date('May 31 2016 11:59:00 AM','MON DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS AM')
  and lower(rid) like '%a001%'
```

Comment: its returns some error like this `SQL Error [1858] [22008]: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

  java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

`

Comment: @QuestionUser I think that it's because you have `AM / PM` in your table fields. What type are the table fields anyway ?

Comment: @KurtMiller i have removed  and i tried its not working :(

Comment: same error `SQL Error [1858] [22008]: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

  java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected @sagi

`

Comment: is this neceesary to change the dateformat in table ? @sagi

Comment: @QuestionUser updated ,  I've just checked this , it should work . What is `FM` mask? Also, you can't use `00:00:00` with `AM/PM` , only 1-12

Comment: sorry the same error again :(.may be due to this we have a problem `12:00:00:000AM` ? @sagi

Comment: Is it stored as date? What's the type of this column ?

Comment: `varchar` @sagi need to chage the datetype ?

Comment: OP seems to have varchar everywhere. I think Avi answers below may be helpful. Plus OP needs to add proper with Meridiam indicators (unless it's a typo in its post)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 select * 
      from RP_REPORT_TEMP 
     where TO_date(START_DATE,'MON DD YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') 
              >= to_Date('May 01 2016 12:00:00 AM' ,'MON DD YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') 
       and TO_DATE(END_DATE,'MON DD YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') 
              <= TO_DATE('May 31 2016 11:59:00 AM' ,'MON DD YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') 
       and lower(rid) like '%a001%' 
     order by CAST(cid as INTEGER) asc
```

---

```
select * 
      from RP_REPORT_TEMP 
     where TO_date(START_DATE,'MON DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
              >= to_Date('May 01 2016 12:00:00' ,'MON DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
       and TO_DATE(END_DATE,'MON DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
              <= TO_DATE('May 31 2016 11:59:00' ,'MON DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
       and lower(rid) like '%a001%' 
     order by CAST(cid as INTEGER) asc
```

Comment: it returns some error like this `SQL Error [1818] [22008]: ORA-01818: 'HH24' precludes use of meridian indicator

  java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01818: 'HH24' precludes use of meridian indicator

`

Comment: @QuestionUser That's because your format is incorrect. Please give an example of a date in your START_DATE column. ETA: ah, whoops, you already did in your question, sorry!

Comment: now returns error like this `SQL Error [1861] [22008]: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

  java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`

Comment: No , actually its because of the `00:00:00` . Change it to `12:00:00` and add AM/PM

Comment: `May  1 2016 12:00:00:000AM` Start date column @Boneist

Comment: Yes, my fault, but the next error will be `Hours must be between 1-12` @Boneist

Comment: did this query have any solution ? @sagi

Comment: @Avi , change `00:00:00` to `12:00:00`

Comment: `SQL Error [1855] [22008]: ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required

  java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` are actually dates, I can spot two main issues in your code:

1. Casting every row to string is slow and also prevents Oracle from using indexes (unless you have a carefully built function-based index).
2. Lexicographical sort (aka "A to Z") does not render meaningful results with dates with "May 1". Just think of what sense this list has: `Apr, Aug, Dec, Feb, Jan, Jul, Jun, Mar, May, Nov, Oct, Sep`

My suggestions are:

- Avoid converting dates to string, save for display purposes
- Use a more solid format when you have to convert from string to date

As a result:

```
select * 
  from RP_REPORT_TEMP 
 where START_DATE
          >= TO_DATE('2016-05-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
   and END_DATE
          <= TO_DATE('2016-05-31 11:59:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
   and lower(rid) like '%a001%' 
 order by CAST(cid as INTEGER) asc
```

---

**P.S.** `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` were not dates after all

Comment: its returns some error like this `SQL Error [1858] [22008]: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected `

Comment: Just look at my first sentence: "Assuming that START_DATE and END_DATE are actually dates". I've just seen your edit where you explain they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your query should look like:

```
select   * 
from     rp_report_temp 
where    to_date(start_date,'FM Mon DD YYYY HH:MI:SS"FMMon DD YYYY HH:MI:SS":000"AM', 'nls_date_language = english') 
            >= to_date('01/05/2016 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
and      to_date(end_date,'FM Mon DD YYYY HH:MI:SS":000"AM', 'nls_date_language = english') 
            <= to_date('31/05/2016 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
and      lower(rid) like '%a001%' 
order by cast(cid as integer) asc;
```

Here, I have converted your start and end date columns into a date, based on the fact that a sample string in that column looks like "May  1 2016 12:00:00:000AM" - there's an extra ":000" after the seconds; I'm assuming this is always ":000".

Note how I've made your code nls_date_language parameter independent, by specifically setting that value within the `to_date()`. This means that if someone else's client has that set to something that's not English, the sql statement will still work for them.

You'll note that I didn't need to do that for the values you're testing, since I changed the format of the string to something that used numbers to represent the months.

You have some fundamental data modelling issues here too - by storing everything as `varchar2` you have made a rod for your own back - you've lost all the validation available (what happens if someone puts a string of `Feb 30 2015 39:99:99 AM` in that column? AWOOGA, AWOOGA, error!). You've made your queries have to work harder (now we've got functions all over the place trying to convert data to the correct datatype).

You should store data in the correct datatype. Dates should be stored as DATE, Timestamps as TIMESTAMP, numbers as NUMBER (with or without specific precision and scale), etc etc.

If your data was stored correctly, then your query would be:

```
select   *
from     rp_report_temp
where    start_date >= to_date('01/05/2016 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
and      end_date <= to_date('31/05/2016 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
and      lower(rid) like '%a001%'
order by cid asc;
```

Comment: `SQL Error [1861] [22008]: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

  java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

`

Comment: I've updated the format. Your start and end date columns are in a really odd format. Is the format meant to take care of milliseconds?

Comment: `SQL Error [1858] [22008]: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

  java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

` :(

Comment: Then the data in your columns aren't always in the expected format. Or your cid column contains values which aren't numbers. This is the danger you run into when you store data in the wrong datatype. I cannot recommend updating the datatypes of your columns highly enough. Honestly, it'll save you so much grief in the long run!